# How to make something global in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UILabel` that I created in my `viewDidLoad` function. Then, I have a function that is outside of the `viewDidLoad` function. I need to be able to access the `UILabel`.

I know I could do that with `extern` in ObjC, but how is it done in Swift?

Comment: Point of clarification, you're looking for how to make something an ivar/property in a class, *not* a global.

Comment: @BergQuester Actually, he is asking how to make it global.  He *should* be asking how to make it a property.

Comment: @David Exactly my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your need you can do it with property declaration something like this:

```
yourViewController : UIViewController {

    var label :UILabel? // your property

    override func viewDidLoad {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        label = UILabel() // an example initialization
    }

    yourMethod {

        label // here you can access your label as 
    }
}
```

that's it.